# Reset/lock html5 canvas position to center on player when panning

Tags: html, canvas

I cannot figure out how to do this. I was translating the character and background at the same time, but if there's any hiccup, the character position slides out of the viewable area of the canvas, and I need the canvas translation to be based off the position of the player (hero.x, hero.y).

Currently I have

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;

//then in my update function
if (38 in keysDown && hero.y > 0){ //UP KEY PRESSED KEY
ctx.translate(0,12);   //translate background position +12y
hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier; //move player up on the background image

else if (40 in keysDown && hero.y < 3750-64){ //DOWN KEY PRESSED
ctx.translate(0, -12); 
hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;    
}
}
```

That moves the player and the canvas but not guaranteed together...if it freezes at all, the player is off center or even off screen.

The viewable canvas area is 640x480, but the background image you can navigate on is 5,000 x 3750.

On the web browser, when it doesn't freeze, it works how I want, moving the player and background at the same pace as the character.

However, that same rate on the phone puts the player much faster than the screen translates which means the player walks right out of the viewable area even though it still moves the background.

**If I do ctx.translate(hero.x, hero.y) and use the hero.x, hero.y coordinates of the player, or some variation of it minus an offset, it moves the background *BY* that measurement each time I press the key instead of moving it *TO* that position.**

How can I make everything conditional on the players position to move both the player and background, but together, or automatically adjust next update() to center on the player....?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make everything conditional on the players position to move both the player and background, but together, or automatically adjust next update() to center on the player

Well, the easy way would be to actually always draw the player in the center! In other words, never ever change or translate his or her coordinates. Instead worrying about translating everything else in relation to that.

Since you want the player to always be in the center, you should always draw the player at the center of the canvas (640/2 x 480/2 for you)

Then you'll want to do is keep a canvas offset for X and Y and draw everything (Background, etc) using that offset, then reset the transformation and draw the hero in the plain old center.

So your draw function might look something like this:

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    // Save the default transformation matrix
    ctx.save();
    // Translate by the background's offset
    ctx.translate(xoffset, yoffset);
    // Draw the background (and maybe other things) translated
    ctx.fillStyle = backgroundGradient; 
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);  
    // We restore to the default transformation
    // This will draw the hero not translated at all
    // That means we can always draw the hero in the center!
    ctx.restore();
    // hero is a black rectangle
    ctx.fillRect(240, 240, 20, 20);
}
```

Here is a live example that works with mouse down and up. There is a big "sun" for the background that moves, while the "stays" rectangle stays still because it is literally always drawn in the same place:

http://jsfiddle.net/3CfFE/

Comment: Ah that makes sense using an offset variable, but dang it's going to be a pain to implement now, how I set things up. I have a 5000 x 3750 background split up into 25 zones with different monsters activated as you enter each different zone. There's also objects, buildings, and all kinds of items drawn strategically all over the background "level". But looking like that's probably the best way, ugh...